# Error on torch_tensor(1, device = "cuda") unable to link with CUDA device

Tags: pytorch

Hi i am using Win 11 and have installed cuda v11.8. after installing torch and `torch_tensor(1, device = "cuda")` I get a error

```
Error in torch_tensor_cpp(data, dtype, device, requires_grad, pin_memory) : 
  PyTorch is not linked with support for cuda devices
Exception raised from getDeviceGuardImpl at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\c10/core/impl/DeviceGuardImplInterface.h:319 (most recent call first):
00007FF967EDAD1200007FF967EDACB0 c10.dll!c10::Error::Error [<unknown file> @ <unknown line number>]
00007FF967EDA79E00007FF967EDA750 c10.dll!c10::detail::torchCheckFail [<unknown file> @ <unknown line number>]
00007FF8AE29EC0500007FF8AE29EA60 torch_cpu.dll!at::Context::getDeviceFromPtr [<unknown file> @ <unknown line number>]
00007FF8AE770A4600007FF8AE7709B0 torch_cpu.dll!at::native::to [<unknown file> @ <unknown line number>]
00007FF8AF45A96800007FF8AF454610 torch_cpu.dll!at::compositeimplicitautograd::where [<unknown file> @ <unknown line number>]
00007FF8AF4440ED00007FF8AF40FAC0 torch_cpu.dll!at::compositeimplicitautograd::broadcast_to [<unknown file> @ <unknown line number]
```

**Is it because of my Cuda version and if so which version can I use?**

Comment: "Unable" and "is not" are too different things. You have a version of pytorch built without GPU support.

Comment: now that you have your `cuda` installed reinstall Pytorch with gpu support.

Comment: thanks @chris will do and update with the results

Comment: hi @Chris i used the command `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118` and downloaded the corresponding file from the terminal while in administrator but still the same error is being shown when I access torch from R is there any step that I have not taken?

Comment: There are both `python` and `R` implementations of `pytorch`, called the `torch` package in R [torch](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/torch/vignettes/installation.html). In R, you need to have LibTorch installed on your system (done). Then I would check if cuda V .11.8 is supported by `torch` [torch issues](https://github.com/mlverse/torch), then proceed with installation of 'torch`. It makes life simpler to install all dependencies and perhaps suggested packages prior to installing your desired package. I think doing this from the R side while in R using `torch`will be easier.

Comment: Thanks @Chris i was able to download torch and am not getting a error in `torch_tensor(1, device = "cuda")`